# How to remove a hole from a polygon in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, polygon

Is it possible to remove a hole from a polygon by using OpenLayers? 
How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out OpenLayers Editor [here](http://ole.geops.de/). it has tool for merging two polygon (merge selected geometry) so you can draw a polygon on to hole then merge two polygons.

[image: editor]

beside this you should check out **JTS Topology Suite** for javascript implementation [here](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts).

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Great input. I will try do solve it this way. Thanks for the help!